# Stop recording a macro in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, ide, macros

I'm developing an Android app in Eclipse Helios and I appear to have accidentally pressed a key combination that starts recording a macro (with Practically Macro):

[image]

**How can I stop recording the macro?**

I can't find it in the Eclipse menus, and I'm finding it surprisingly hard to find an answer on the web!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You start recording a macro using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> and stop in the same way.

You can also use the buttons on the toolbar:

[image: PracticallyMacro toolbar buttons]

Comment: Thanks, that does it!  I did see those buttons on the toolbar, but their tooltips are "Record Macro (Ctrl+Alt+R)", "Quick play a command (Ctrl+Alt+Q)" and "Play Macro (Ctrl+Alt+P)" - so it wasn't very obvious that "Record Macro" would stop the recording!

Comment: Also, it usually stops recording if you close the current file.